# How to transfer BlackBerry 9700 contacts to Android phone?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry 9700 BOLD and a Samsung Galaxy SIII and I need to transfer as much of my contact info from the BB to the Galaxy SIII. I already know that if I save numbers on my SIM card they will be transferred but I can't save everything on it.

I read a lot of articles about using "Google Sync" app for BlackBerry to sync with Google's cloud and then back to Android again. But the problem is that I went there now http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/ and it seems they stopped BlackBerry support for Google Sync.

So my question is how to sync as much of my data from BlackBerry to my Android phone without using Google Sync?

Comment: Can you export the contact data? To a CSV file, perhaps?

Comment: I should be able to. Out of curiosity I searched on GooglePlay and I Found a free app called Rainbow Contacts which seems to be very very promising. I Will try it tonight.

Comment: RainbowContacts worked great. Imported 252 contacts but the app crashed when it was done.

Answer (score 5):

Used [RainbowContacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pip.UIofPIP) app for Android to connect to BlackBerry via Bluetooth and import contacts.

Answer (score 4):

## Transferring Blackberry contacts to Android

Galaxy Note 2

1. Turn on Bluetooth for both devices
2. Pair both devices to each other
3. Go to Blackberry's Bluetooth setup, and select the Android phone- for me it's SGH-T889 renamed Galaxy Note 2.
4. Press the enter key or trackpad, and the device menu will pop up.
5. Select  "Transfer Contacts"
6. Your Android device will popup a request to accept a file named Phonebook.vcf'. Choose ACCEPT
7. Your Android will now accept your complete contact list!
8. Your welcome! Now if your in LA  buy me a chocolate
   puddinf cake and a Coke. My name is Paul.

Answer (score 0):

After going through some useless posts all over the internet, I came across one app in BB App World - [Quick Contact Transfer](https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/reviews/129488/). This works great. You may need to shell out few rupees to buy it though.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issues with this transfer also. I had problems on transferring my notes to the Android platform. I have literally hundreds of notes and a lot of task items. I could not figure out how to transfer them.

Then I found this little app that makes it much easier. It uses my blackberry backup file to transfer even my sms texts from the blackberry to android.

Oh! The name of the app 2can look it up on Google Play.

Sweet.

Comment: You can't even bother to provide a link?

Answer (score -2):

I had a B9700, too. And i know many apps don't support b9700 bold. But i found one called NetQin Contacts Sync, and it did a wonderful job!

It did just what it advertised to do, done the task in seconds. NetQin Sync is available for blackberries, android phones and iphones, so moving contacts from one of the three to another is no problem for NetQin. And, it is completely free!

you can check out the procedures here:
http://be-tasty-azur.blogspot.tw/2012/11/how-to-move-contacts-to-android-iphone.html